# Getting Error Pipe Notifications bind failure "Bucket already bound from another Snowflake account"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the error: **Pipe Notifications bind failure "Bucket already bound from another Snowflake account"**

We have 2 accounts, so I removed the bucket references from one account, but I am still getting this error. I have an S3 Integration setup.

Do I need to re-do the integration to get this working properly? I am unable to create additional / new transforms on this pipe.

Does this require Snowflake hands to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone (bstora) answered this yesterday with a correct answer, I'm not sure why it's been deleted, but it was 100% correct.

So, to rewrite what they wrote, if this happens to you then you will need to reach out to Snowflake Support to have them determine the correct course of action.  There is currently no action you can take as a user to correct or fix this.

This page will show you how to create a support ticket, if you haven't created one in the past.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: Yes I reached out and it was resolved in about an hour.